# How to define a C# object at run time?

Tags: c#, dynamic, object

We have XML code stored in a single relational database field to get around the Entity / Attribute / Value database issues, however I don't want this to ruin my Domain Modeling, DTO, and Repository sunshine.  I cannot get around the EAV/CR content, but I can choose how to store it.  Question is how would I use it?

How could I turn the XML metadata in to a class / object at run time in C#?

For example:

XML would describe that we have a food recipe which has various attributes, but usually similar, and one or more attributes about making the food.  The food itself can literally be anything and have any type of crazy preparation.  All attributes are searched and may link to existing nutritional information.

```
// <-- [Model validation annotation goes here for MVC2]
public class Pizza {
     public string kind  {get; set;}
     public string shape {get; set;}
     public string city  {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

and in the ActionMethod:

```
makePizzaActionMethod (Pizza myPizza) {
    if (myPizza.isValid() ) {  // this is probably ModelState.isValid()...
        myRecipeRepository.Save( myPizza);
        return View("Saved");
    }
    else
        return View();
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the Repository wouldn't be Pizza specific.

Comment: Does the XML have a schema? Then you can use the schema to generate code. If not, then you need a dynamic language, not C#.

Comment: We can have a schema for the XML.  The class of recipe actually doesn't change once it exists, but new recipe classes can be created on the fly.  I would say about 15-20 recipe classes per customer type, and we have many different kinds of customers, all of whom enjoy eating.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What sort of object do you want to have at the end? Can't you just load all the XML into a map/tree structure? Or do you want it to be typed classes? If it needs to be typed classes, obviously you'll just need to load that XML into a type-structure that you've already defined. This seems incredibly trivial. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I  agree with Silky, either use a generic list/map or if (as you say) the class of recipe wont change, generate the classes and deserialize. Sounds like you might be over-engineeering.

Comment: Originally, we had an EAV/CR where the C stands for classes.  We had three tables per entity, where one listed the data types of the fields for the class, their names, what labels to use on the forms, etc.  Now we just need to represent all these different classes in a good way.  I have not worked enough with XML and C# to know how to do this.  Incredibly trivial sounds really good to me.

Comment: @Dr. Zim: Ah, okay then. Just check out a few tutorials on Xml Serialisation in C#, it's easy enough. This may be a good one (http://www.dotnetjohn.com/PrintFriend.aspx?articleid=173).

Comment: @silky - I really want to create a class from the XML mini-schema then deserialize the data in to it from the database. I think that may be slightly opposite from the article mentioned above. Of course, I don't read anymore, I scan. LOL

Comment: Zim: Perhaps you should read :) Indeed if you do create the schema, and have the ability for your classes to serialise directly to that format, it is then possible to bring them back into class objects via the reverse process (which I think that article describes; if not, it's easy enough to find via searching).

Comment: What would you do with the additional properties on the class? How would you access them when you don't know they exist?

Comment: Actually, I was hoping to have UI Templates created specifically to match the classes.  EditorFor(m => m) where m is a Pizza class using Pizza.ascx in the EditorTemplates folder.

Comment: Our software presents a work flow that customers love.  They can define their widgets within the software.  We don't know a lot about these widgets, except they have a lot of string properties, validated by RegEx, and they eventually relate to real physical properties like Price, Cost, etc.

Comment: Imaging doing a foreach on the object properties and sending them to an EditorFor(m => property).  If it is a date, it shows the JQuery date editor view template we setup.  Whether the date property exists is up to the customer.

Comment: In scanning over validation attributes, I think I saw it enumerating the objects properties through reflection.  At least that's what got me thinking of all of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28VS.100%29.aspx) what you're looking for?

> Represents an object whose members can
>   be dynamically added and removed at
>   run time.

Comment: Wow.  Now that is a good application of knowledge to a particular problem.  I am going to let the question ride for a bit, but this answer is very nice.

Comment: I find this very disturbing, personally. But I suppose this isn't the place to debate the merits of this "thing".

Comment: Welcome to the brave new world of dynamic c#.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(VS.80).aspx) namespace.

You Start with an AssemblyBuilder class from AppDomain.CurrentDomain

```
AssemblyBuilder dynAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly("dynamic.dll",
                                                                            AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
```

From there you have to build a ModuleBuilder, from which you can build a TypeBuilder.

Check out the [AssmblyBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.aspx) reference for an example.

You can save the generated assembly, or you can just use it in memory.  Be warned though, that you will get heavy into reflection to use these dynamic types.

EDIT:

Below is an example of how to iterate through the properties:

```
AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("dynamic");
AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("dynamic.dll");
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("Pizza");
//Define your type here based on the info in your xml
Type theType = tb.CreateType();

//instanciate your object
ConstructorInfo ctor = theType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
object inst = ctor.Invoke(new object[]{});

PropertyInfo[] pList = theType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
//iterate through all the properties of the instance 'inst' of your new Type
foreach(PropertyInfo pi in pList)
    Console.WriteLine(pi.GetValue(inst, null));
```

Comment: I still don't see how such a class could be used, since code does not know about the additional properties.

Comment: You can iterate through the Properties of the new type using the associated Type class I will add an example above.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This does not address the original poster's question.

I think that this may be possible using [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx). I would generate a XAML file, and then [load it dynamically using XamlReader.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590398.aspx) create an object at run-time with the properties I want.

There is an interesting article to read on the subject of [XAML as an object serialization framework here](http://en.csharp-online.net/XAML%E2%80%94Using_Types_from_Other_Namespaces). For more information on [XAML namespaces see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2007/05/16/NamespacesInXaml.aspx).

Comment: @cdiggins: -1: I can't imagine how XAML will help. I'll remove the downvote if you assist my imagination.

Comment: Added some clarification. You can create dynamic objects with XamlReader.Load(), isn't this going to work Dr. Zim's case? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you give an example? Because I don't believe you.

Comment: Button readerLoadButton = (Button)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
It does create objects from xml, however it may be limited to the Xaml namespace though.

Comment: There still needs to be a class defined for the XamlReader to materialise -- e.g. a Pizza class.  XAML won't create the class for you, but it will create instances of the class from XML once the class exists.  And I think Dr Zim's problem is more around the creation of the class than around the reading in from XML.

Comment: Dr Zim: XAML is not limited to the XAML namespace (I've used XamlReader successfully to read in e.g. business rules), but you would need to provide your own namespace mappings for things that aren't in the XAML namespace.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I do know that XAML is a generic object serialization framework (not just limited to WPF). I am looking into rolling a demo but I'll add some links to my answer.

Comment: @itowlson - I upvoted your comment.  You nailed it: creating a class from the XML mini-schema.